# In my laptop command promt did not recognize the desktoo

Tags: javascript, python

I did not access the file on desktop by command prompt.by using command prompt I  will complie and run the program.what should I do

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you have your Program File on the desktop and you want to launch Command Prompt there to complie/run it, you can do this:

On your Desktop, hold shift and right click. You'll see an option: open command prompt here. Click it.
It'll launch the command prompt window there and then you can run your file.
Ex: C://User/Desktop/python file.py